# Can not see banner - admob plugin

Tags: admob, coronasdk

I have a problem with the new admob plugin of corona-sdk platform.

In one hand, I have an app that I already published to Google Play long time ago and yesterday I purchashed the new admob plugin, so I rebuild the app and add an ad banner using the new admob plugin - It worked propely.

On the other hand, I have an app that I did not published yet (brand new), I tried to add a banner using the new admob plugin (the SAME way I did with the other app - same code same everything - also the build.setting).
I can see an ad only if it's using TestMode=true.

This is how I did it:
I have the main.lua init the ad:

```
-- AdMob listener function
local function adListener( event )
    if ( event.phase == "init" ) then  -- Successful initialization
        -- Load an AdMob interstitial ad
        admob.load( "banner", { adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxx/xxxxx" } )
    end
end

-- Initialize the AdMob plugin
admob.init( adListener, { appId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxx~xxxxxxx"} )
```

and in an scene I do this:

```
if ( admob.isLoaded( "banner" ) ) then
            bannerHeight = admob.height()
            admob.show( "banner", { y = display.actualContentHeight - bannerHeight} )
end
```

I tried everything, I know the ad unit works because I check it on the first app that the banner works there.
My only thought left is that maybe it's happenning becuase I didn't published the app yet..

Hope for help, Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a while until Admob start serving you ads, even if your account is not new, check if the return error code is `3` (lack of ads) - if so, you're fine

Answer (score 0):

You asked a very similar question here:

[Admob response loadFaild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53575020/admob-response-loadfaild/53685073#53685073)

You are not permitted to show live ads in a test app per AdMob's rules. While testing you need to have testMode = true.

Rob