# Admob response loadFaild

Tags: android, ios, admob, coronasdk

I have built a Corona SDK app that I want to contains ads (using an Admob).

I have 2 apps: one that I already published to the Google play and what I needed now is to republish it with an ad banner. And a second app that I haven't published at all.

When I tried to insert banner to my app that I already published it's shows the banner properly but when I tried to add the SAME impletation to the app I haven't published yet I received constantly "error code 3".

So, my question is: Is admob require that the app will be published in the "Google Play" store to be able to get ads?

Thank all.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the ads to use testMode? If your app isn't published yet, you should not be getting live ads. But if you haven't published yet, you're not allowed to show live ads.

See: http://docs.coronalabs.com/plugin/admob/init.html

Rob